# Chrome fires scroll event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

There is simple code

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        alert('asd');
    });
};
```

when you refresh scrolled page, in firefox - you wont see alert, but in chrome SOMETIMES, it fires alert, sometimes its not. Same page, same scroll, just multiple refreshes.

Question is how to avoid triggering scroll event on load in chrome after refresh?

Problem is, DOMContentLoaded can solve this, but i have block animation with coordinates on scroll (scroll-then-fixed), and with DOMContentLoaded coordinates are wrong.

p.s. No $@#$ jQuery allowed.

p.s.2.

```
    if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
        history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    }
```

is not fix, but workaround too.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
var tFn = function (){
    alert();
}
document.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if ( document.readyState == ("complete") ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.onscroll = tFn;
        },100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason why this is necessary? What is the difference between this and "onload"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could track the initial scroll with a flag and detect whether the page did not actually scroll:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var isFirstTime = true;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            isFirstTime = false;
            if (window.scrollY === 0) return;
        }
        alert('asd');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
console.log('Scrolling');

};

</script>
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question ?